# Trignometry problem: If $\sin^2\theta + 3\cos\theta = 2$ then find $\cos^3\theta + \frac{1}{\cos^3\theta}$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin^2\theta + 3\cos\theta = 2$ then find $\cos^3\theta + \frac{1}{\cos^3\theta}$

What I did: 
$\sin^2\theta + 3\cos\theta = 2$ 
$3\cos\theta - 1 = 1 - \sin^2\theta$ 
$3\cos\theta - 1 = \cos^2\theta$ 
$\cos^3\theta + \frac{1}{\cos^3\theta} = (\cos^2\theta + 1)^3 + \frac{1}{(\cos^2\theta + 1)^3}$

Then I'll have to take LCM and it would be bigger. Can anyone suggest an easy way to solve this problem?

Comment: From $3\cos(\theta)-1=\cos^2(\theta)$, dividing by $\cos(\theta)$ (which must be non-zero), you get $\cos(\theta)+\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}=3$. Remember that $x^3+x^{-3}=(x+x^{-1})^3-3(x+x^{-1})$. Put in that formula $x=\cos(\theta)$. You get that $\cos^3(\theta)+\frac{1}{\cos^3(\theta)}=3^3-3\cdot 3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $c=\cos\theta$. From what you found, we have
$$c+\frac{1}{c}=3.$$
Then,
$$c^3+\frac{1}{c^3}=(c+\frac{1}{c})^3-3(c+\frac{1}{c})=3^3-3\times 3=18.$$

Answer (score 3):

From $3\cos\theta-1=\cos^2\theta$, let $u=\cos\theta$.  Then you have the quadratic $u^2-3u+1=0$.  Solving this quadratic gives $u_+=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}2$ and $u_-=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}2$.  Note that $u_+>1$, and therefore it is not a valid solution to $u=\cos\theta$.

Now, you need to find $u^3+u^{-3}$.  Plugging in $u_-$, you get $u^3+u^{-3}=\frac{27-27\sqrt{5}+45-5\sqrt{5}}{8}+\frac{8}{27-27\sqrt{5}+45-5\sqrt{5}}=\frac{72-32\sqrt{5}}{8}+\frac{8}{72-32\sqrt{5}}=\frac{(72-32\sqrt{5})^2}{8(72-32\sqrt{5})}+\frac{64}{8(72-32\sqrt{5})}=\frac{5184-4608\sqrt{5}+5120+64}{576-256\sqrt{5}}=\frac{10368-4608\sqrt{5}}{576-256\sqrt{5}}=\frac{64(162-72\sqrt{5})}{64(9-4\sqrt{5})}=\frac{162-72\sqrt{5})}{9-4\sqrt{5}}=\frac{(9+4\sqrt{5})(162-72\sqrt{5})}{(9+4\sqrt{5})(9-4\sqrt{5})}=\frac{1458+648\sqrt{5}-648\sqrt{5}-1440}{81-80}=\frac{18}{1}=18$

Comment: It is long and not suitable for MCQ type questions. I will give and upvote though